# Not able to show items selected by default with ionic fancy select directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic multi select. According, to ionic fancy select in **items** we need to initialize the selectable items and in **selected** we can add some items to be checked by default.

As, per the directive I have added some element's in $scope.selected and in html I gave selected = "selected". But, the items I added in $scope.selected are marked as checked by default. I have added a plunker link where I have tried this. https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlhZOZVcDGuIxRyEtCfv?p=preview

In script.js:

```
$scope.selectable = [{
        "fname" : "Ghaffar",
        "lname" : "Peterman",
        "group" : "Good"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Arturo",
        "lname" : "Sessa",
        "group" : "Good"
    }, ....{
        "fname" : "Marqueal",
        "lname" : "Wright",
        "group" : "Better"
    }
];

$scope.selected = [{
        "fname" : "Ghaffar",
        "lname" : "Peterman",
        "group" : "Good"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Arturo",
        "lname" : "Sessa",
        "group" : "Good"
    }
];
```

In html:

```
 <div class="item item-select" fancy-select ng-model="multi1" multi-select="true" items="selectable" selected ="selected" item-label="fname+ ' ' +lname">
    {{parseMulti(multi1) || 'Select Items'}}
 </div>
```

Kindly, help me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `selected: true` property to the elements selected by default in `selectable` array:

```
  $scope.selectable = [{
    "fname": "Ghaffar",
    "lname": "Peterman",
    "group": "Good",
    selected: true
  }, {
    "fname": "Arturo",
    "lname": "Sessa",
    "group": "Good",
    selected: true
  }, {
    "fname": "Bilal",
    "lname": "Cox",
    "group": "Best"
  }
  ...
```

Then I populated the `selected` array using a forEach() cycle.

I think the `ng-model` and `ng-selected` should be the same scope variable.

here is the Plunker updated: https://plnkr.co/edit/7RP8cx1Z1rm4Lrbz7DBf

Comment: Thank you , worked like a gem. I have another issue with this plugin shall I create another issue and post the url here, Can you help me on that if you don't mind.